# Text Writing Animation like word2013

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I was wondering, if I can make a TextBox or any control that you can write some text on it, to be like Word 2013, the animation experience is very good.

I am now able to do type of animation on the control itself (TextBox,...), but to do this type of animation to the cursor or on the text itself this is new.

[image]
[image]

Comment: For clarity (and those who haven't seen), the cursor in Office 2013 has a sweep animation as it moves between characters (including when you type, or if you click around an Excel spreadsheet).

Comment: If I'm not wrong, but perhaps this decision will not be easy. `Animation` in the `TextBox` is limited developers because of feature `WPF` rendering. For example, the text property is not a dependency property, so the animation he can not involved. On the other hand, in the `MS Office` working it and hope is implemented normally. So there is hope for a solution... but on what?

Comment: Personally, I really do hate all these animations in Office 2013 a very very lot. AAAAARGH!

Comment: @UweKeim While I personally like them, they can be [turned off](http://winsupersite.com/article/office-2013-beta2/office-2013-tip-disable-animations-143779)

Comment: @ghord Wow, what a great relieve. Thank you very much!

Comment: If anyone wonders what it looks like: [Awful typing animation in Word 15](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ck9Puso8crQ).

Comment: Wow, that ***is*** awful @Athari. Why would anyone want to copy this in their own app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a WPF UserControl or custom control which inherits from the default WPF textbox.  I was able to create a textbox that animates the cursor position with the following method:

1-Create a user control and add a textbox to it.

2-Add a canvas with a rectangle inside it (the rectangle is your new cursor).

3-Set the Texboxes CaretBrush to transparent.

4-In the UserControl's code-behind create a method to animate the cursor when the cursor position changes.

5-Call the animation method from step 4 when certain events happen which would change the cursor position.

Example:

UserControl XAML

```
    <UserControl
        x:Class="YourNamespace.AnimatedCursorTextBox"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignHeight="23"
        d:DesignWidth="300"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=PresentationFramework"
        Name="Control">
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <c:BooleanToVisibilityConverter
                x:Key="BoolToVisibility" />
        </UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <TextBox
                Name="MainTextBox"
                CaretBrush="Transparent"
                SelectionChanged="MainTextBox_SelectionChanged"
                TextChanged="MainTextBox_TextChanged"
                GotKeyboardFocus="MainTextBox_GotKeyboardFocus" />
            <Canvas
                Visibility="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin,
                    ElementName=Control,
                    Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"
                Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=MainTextBox}"
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainTextBox}">
                <Rectangle
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Name="Caret"
                    Width="1"
                    Fill="Black" />
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Code-Behind:

```
    public partial class AnimatedCursorTextBox : UserControl
        {
            private DoubleAnimation cursorAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

            public AnimatedCursorTextBox()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void UpdateCaretPosition()
            {
                var rectangle = MainTextBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(MainTextBox.CaretIndex);
                Caret.Height = rectangle.Bottom - rectangle.Top;
                Canvas.SetTop(Caret, rectangle.Top);
                Canvas.SetBottom(Caret, rectangle.Bottom);

                var left = Canvas.GetLeft(Caret);
                if (!double.IsNaN(left))
                {
                    cursorAnimation.From = left;
                    cursorAnimation.To = rectangle.Right;
                    cursorAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.05));

                    Caret.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, cursorAnimation);
                }
                else
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(Caret, rectangle.Right);
                }
            }

            private void MainTextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                UpdateCaretPosition();
            }

            private void MainTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                UpdateCaretPosition();
            }

            private void MainTextBox_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                UpdateCaretPosition();
            }
        }
```

Note: This isn't a comprehensive solution because it doesn't handle the animation of highlighting selected text and it doesn't hide the cursor when text is highlighted, but it is a start.  I recommend creating this as a custom control inheriting from TextBox and then do the layout of the control in the textbox's default style's template rather than using a UserControl. That way you can preserve all the functionality of TextBox but still get the new animation features.  For more information about Custom Controls in WPF see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35444/Defining-the-Default-Style-for-a-Lookless-Control) article on codeproject.

To change the speed of the animation just change the duration of the cursorAnimation.